# Create a validation rule that allows a specific user to edit account websites but not another specific user

Tags: validation-rule

I have a request to create a validation rule that allows a specific user to edit account websites but not another specific user.

I have tried working this out but cannot seem to put it together.

Comment: Just for clarity, can you provide a few more details? Are both users in the same profile? Do they both have edit FLS on the Account Website field?

Comment: The one who needs to be able to edit the field is a Standard Platform User, the one who needs to not be able to edit the field is a Standard User.

Comment: I was able to accomplish it with this formula.

AND(
NOT(ISNEW()),
ISCHANGED(Website),
$User.Username = blocked.user@your.org"
)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom permission and a permission set to give that custom permission to a specific user. And a validation rule referring that custom permission

See  details here
[https://www.salesforcechris.com/custom-permissions-in-validation-rules/#:~:text=Custom%20permissions%20can%20be%20referenced,without%20touching%20the%20rule%20again](https://www.salesforcechris.com/custom-permissions-in-validation-rules/#:%7E:text=Custom%20permissions%20can%20be%20referenced,without%20touching%20the%20rule%20again).